# React consumes API in development, fails after deployment

Tags: reactjs, deployment, axios, web-deployment, aws-amplify

please help me with the following problem as it already taken me so much time to figure out:

I have an API which I created using PHP and hosted with AWS EC2.

This API is to be consumed by a React frontend app I made, and when I am developing the frontend there are no problems sending and receiving data from the API.

However, after I deploy the app using AWS Amplify, the app loads correctly but fails to connect to the api(i.e. not showing fetched data, unable to post forms)

I read a little bit about proxying but I am not sure it is the solution and if so, how would I implement it.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: post the error message

Comment: There are no errors, my app is located at:
https://main.d77ic2fj0mpnm.amplifyapp.com/

Comment: Is the problem the timeout of https://ec2-15-237-63-16.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com/movie-comparison/movies/get ?

If you call the URL directly it also can't be reached. Are there any restriction in the security group of the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue.
My problem was that the server was not listening to https port, so the browser blocked the content.